# Packer.IO Error uploading file/script

Tags: docker

Whatever I try to upload with Packer to a new provisioned docker image is fails with:

```
==> docker: Pausing before cleanup of step 'StepPull'. Press enter to continue. 
==> docker: Pausing before cleanup of step 'StepTempDir'. Press enter to continue. Build 'docker' errored: Upload failed with non-zero exit status: 1
Build 'docker' errored: Retryable error: Error uploading script: Upload failed with non-zero exit status: 1
```

Debug doesn't really help.

My config part:

```
{
  "type": "file",
  "source": "/home/vm/site",
  "destination": "/var/www/web"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to run Packer inside a Docker container with Docker builder, then you will face an error above. Packer doesn't support provisioning  Docker images inside another Docker container. Here is [GitHub](https://github.com/mitchellh/packer/issues/4559) issue related to this.